# Neo4j: Shortest Path with Cost Function depending on two Consecutive Relations in Path

Tags: neo4j, dijkstra, shortest-path

Say I have a graph with nodes representing cities and and relations representing possible connections between cities. A connection has a departure and an arrival time. I want to find the shortest path between cities `A` and `B` and the cost function is the total travel time. The travel time is the sum of waiting times between connections and connection times.

I'm using the Java API and I have tried using the Dijkstra algorithm using `GraphAlgoFactory.dijkstra(expander, costEvaluator)`. My main problem seems to be, that the `CostEvaluator` interface only receives the current relation and not the complete path. This way I can compute the connection duration but not the waiting time.

Is there something I can do to adapt the existing algorithm or do I have to reimplement Dijkstra?

Comment: Can you confirm that `waiting_time` is the result of `departure_time - arrival_time` ?

Comment: I clarified below.

Answer (score 0):

The total cost of a path will be the sum of the `getCost()` returned values of every evaluation of the given relationship, so just define how the cost should be evaluated on the relationship level, what the total cost will be is evaluated by the algorithm itself.

On the other hand, you can do it with Cypher, assuming the waiting time is the difference between `departure_time` and `arrival_time` :

```
MATCH p=(a:City {name:"NY"})-[r:CONNECTS*..10]->(b:City {name:"LA"})
WITH p, reduce(
  cost=0, x IN rels(p) | cost + (x.departure_time - x.arrival_time) 
) as cost
RETURN p, cost
ORDER BY cost ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Is the Cypher version optimized?

Comment: No, the dijkstra algorithm will perform better, give it a shot, I don't have the opportunity to test it now

Comment: I have a lot of data, so performance is important. Also, I think there is a misunderstanding. The cost of a relation `r` should be `r.arrival - r.departure + r.departure - r_previous.arrival` which can be simplified to `r.departure - r_previous.arrival`.

Comment: Ok ok, I'll check for a better implementation then

Comment: Note that in that case, I tend to make "connection" nodes, because the idea of Connection is something important at my domain level

Comment: Adding connection nodes is not the problem, but I would still need to know when the previous connection arrived.